# How to shift date of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                KWH  
Timestamp            
2017-04-02  1588.06  
2017-04-03  1555.54  
2017-04-04  1604.32  
2017-04-05  1634.13  
2017-04-06  1617.87  
2017-04-07  1598.90  
2017-04-08  1596.19  
2017-04-09  1607.03  
2017-04-10  1601.61  
2017-04-11  1547.41
```

I am trying to shift the index by -1 but it is throwing an error.

I tried this:

```
(df.shift(-1, freq = "D"))
```

Error I got:

> NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Index

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of error? Solution should works.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error.

Comment: if the index are datetimes, you can do `df.index = df.index - pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html), because `Timestamp` is also `index`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1 = df.shift(-1, freq = "D")
print (df1)
                KWH
Timestamp          
2017-04-01  1588.06
2017-04-02  1555.54
2017-04-03  1604.32
2017-04-04  1634.13
2017-04-05  1617.87
2017-04-06  1598.90
2017-04-07  1596.19
2017-04-08  1607.03
2017-04-09  1601.61
2017-04-10  1547.41
```